# a strange issue about python private method

Tags: python

I know everything is public in python, and we just treated these variables with double underscore as private variables,  but we can access these variables out of class in other ways.  but I met some issues when I test the following code.

```
class SA:
    def __myPrivate(self,name):
        return 'private'+name
    def _myProtected(self):
        self.name = 'protected name'    
    def setName(self,name):
        self.name = self.__myPrivate(name)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def printf(self):
        print self.name   

si = SA()
print si._SA_myPrivate('niutou')
```

**the exception is :**

```
print si._SA_myPrivate('niutou')
AttributeError: SA instance has no attribute '_SA_myPrivate'
```

why? please help me to solve this problem. thanks！

**yes, I realized I made a low-level mistake！ it should be si.*SA*_myPrivate('niutou') not si._SA_myPrivate('niutou')**

Comment: Read the second paragraph of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: Probably because you never define a `_SA_myPrivate` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
>>> print si._SA__myPrivate('niutou')
privateniutou
```

Note the double `_`.  The magic replacement keeps that, only append an `_ + classname` when that attribute is converted.

Comment: I do not understand you, can you explain it in more detail? thanks!

Comment: As the highest rated comment pointed to you: read the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references